# Words originating with Thomas Hardy

Tags: etymology

I'm teaching a Thomas Hardy class and read somewhere that Hardy was the originator of over 100 common English words in use today. However, I can only find a list of a few. Does anyone know where I can find more? I don't have access to the OED, nor does my college or town library. And I have spent much time searching google.

Comment: Lloyd Siemans, 1993: "In addition, he coined over two hundred words and fabricated as many alliterative compounds (Hickson 12-27, 48-50)", writing in *Victorian Review*, vol. 19 no. 1, 1993, pp. 43-48. I don't have access, but if you're working for a moderately respectable college or university, you will have, not only to the Siemans, but to the Hickson.

Answer (score 8):

The OED has its first citation of the following words from Hardy. (That doesn't necessarily mean he coined them all)

- angle (= 'an act of angling')
- aquatinted
- ashlared
- asseveratingly
- back-along
- balconette
- challengeful
- cidery
- coquettishness
- crack-voiced
- dand
- datal
- declaim (n)
- deframe
- disillusive
- ditchless
- formularism
- fountain (v)
- gownless
- grintern
- grizzel (adv)
- hanker (n)
- hauling (adj)
- home-along
- hoosh (int)
- hurdler
- inanimately
- indemn (v)
- inheld
- intervolve (n)
- judge and jury (v)
- junctive
- larry
- lastage
- lection (v)
- loiter (n)
- maidy
- misadventurer
- miss-mark
- mumbudget
- nadiral
- necessitator
- off-licence
- ostracizer
- passager
- personalized
- perusing
- petite mort
- playward
- presciencelessness
- rafted ("disturbed, unsettled")
- rafting ("that rouses or stirs up")
- rum-strum (v)
- skitty-bats/skitty boots
- spatter (n "a spatterdash or gaiter")
- stale (n)
- strumming (adj)
- tardle (n)
- transfixture
- treadle (v)
- uncabined
- undergovernment
- unglamoured
- vigil (v)
- warden (v)
- waying (n)
- weedery (n: "mourning garments")
- whorage
- years-long

Comment: Wonderful...there are more than a couple I'm gonna have to look up.:)

Answer (score 3):

The article *[Thomas Hardy’s lexical landscape](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2017/06/02/thomas-hardys-lexical-landscape/)* in the *Oxford Dictionaries Blog* notes quite a few, with links to their entries in the online edition of the OED (such as the entry for [Wessex](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/227882?redirectedFrom=Wessex#eid)). You can apparently browse the definitions with requiring a subscription.

A [limited-time offer](https://public.oed.com/help/) that you might wish to explore:

> The Oxford English Dictionary is available by subscription to
>   institutions and individuals.
>
> To celebrate the OED‘s 90th birthday, we are pleased to offer annual
>   individual OED subscriptions at a reduced rate of $90 in the US
>   (usually $295)  or £90 for the Rest of the World (usually £215) for
>   annual subscriptions taken out between 1 April 2018 until 31 March
>   2019. For this annual rate, you’ll have full unrestricted access to the OED Online – including quarterly updates!